# Prove that: $\mathbb{P}(A \backslash B) = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B), B \subseteq A \subseteq \Omega \land \mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A)$

Tags: probability, proof-writing

> Prove that: $$\mathbb{P}(A \backslash B) = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(B), B \subseteq A \subseteq \Omega \land \mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{P}(A)$$

Additionally, we know that for all $A, B \subseteq \Omega$ we have that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. When I draw a Venn Diagram, I can see that the statement holds however, I'm not sure how I can prove this mathematically.

Comment: if $B\subseteq A$, how is $A \cap B = \emptyset$ (unless $B = \emptyset$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the monotonicity of the probability measure, if $B\subseteq A$, then $\mathbb{P}(B)\leq\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Moreover, since $B\subseteq A$, we can state that $A = (A\backslash B)\cup B$. Indeed, this is the case:
\begin{align*}
(A\backslash B)\cup B & = (A\cap B^{c})\cup B\\\\
& = (A\cup B)\cap (B^{c}\cup B)\\\\
& = (A\cup B)\cap\Omega\\\\
& = A\cup B\\\\
& = A
\end{align*}

Finally, due the finite additive property of the probability measure, since $(A\backslash B)\cap B = \varnothing$ it results that:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) & = \mathbb{P}((A\backslash B)\cup B)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(A\backslash B) + \mathbb{P}(B)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!